# Replicate Hashmap readout in JS

Tags: javascript, java, hashmap

How can I replicate the input of the below hashmap written in Java so that, using the same data, I get the same sign string in Javascript?

Java Code

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("api_key", apiKey);
map.put("sign_type", signType);
map.put("timestamp", timestamp);
String sign = MD5Util.createSign(map, apiSecret);
```

My Attempt in JavaScript

```
let signData= `${api}${signType}${nonce}`;
let sign = Crypto.createHmac('MD5', apiSecret).update(signData).digest('hex')
```

I'm getting two different sign strings and dont know why.

Comment: That would depend on how `MD5Util` is serialising the map to a string, wouldn't it? And I'd assume it just uses the default `toString()`, so it's really a question of whether your JS string matches with the Java string. Unless `MD5Util` doesn't use that as the value.

Comment: I looked into your serializing comment and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993752/hashmap-serialization-and-deserialization-changes says they're serialized `{apiKey=${api}, signType=${signType}, timestamp=${timestamp}}` I tried it and still no dice, so to your second point I dont quite understand what you're saying.  Unless the MD5Util doesnt use what as the value?

Comment: Unless it doesn't use the `toString()` output as its value. Who knows, it might use `hashCode()` (I slightly doubt it but it's possible) or it might implement its own custom logic when it comes to objects. I'm just guessing here - if you get different results, it means that the inputs are different. The MD5 algorithm should work the same and I'd assume that the `apiSecret` is the same, as well. That only leaves the map input as a variable.